# Apache Ivy multiproject dependency declaration

Tags: ant, ivy

I have 2 projects, but Apache Ivy is not able to detect dependency from one to other (I am doing something wrong, but I am not able to see what it is)

2 projects are in separate top level dirs as below

> chainedresolvers-project
>
> dep-project

project1  ivy

```
<ivy-module version="1.0">
    <info organisation="myreports" module="chained-resolvers" status="integration"/>
     <publications>
      <artifact name="myapp" type="jar" conf="default" />
    </publications>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="commons-lang" name="commons-lang" rev="2.0" conf="default"/>
        <dependency name="test" rev="1.0"/>
        <dependency name="rwrun" rev="latest"/>
    </dependencies> </ivy-module>
```

project2  ivy (dep on project1)

```
<ivy-module version="1.0">
    <info organisation="myreports" module="dep-project" status="integration"/>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency name="chained-resolvers" rev="latest.integration" conf="default"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

when i run ant on the 2nd project

```
 ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
 ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
 ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
 :: myreports#chained-resolvers;latest.integration: not found 
 ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

pls comment what i could be doing wrong that it is not able to pickup the dependency ?

Comment: did you publish the 2nd project to the repository and is it there? try running ant in verbode mode (-v). Then ivy will tell you exactly where it is looking for project2.

Answer (score 2):

Due to

```
<publications>
      <artifact name="myapp" type="jar" conf="default" />
    </publications>
```

the name of your artifact is myapp 
therefore the dependency has to be:

```
<ivy-module version="1.0">
    <info organisation="myreports" module="dep-project" status="integration"/>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency organisation="myreports" name="myapp" rev="latest.integration" conf="default"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Comment: - Thanks All
- in 2nd project, ant -v told me, it was looking for something like <jarname>-<rev>.jar in the paths given by <resolvers> in ivysettings.xml file
- in my first project i jar ed it in a ant target with above name and put it in a path given by <resolvers> 
then it was able to find from 2nd project 

(i guess this was one way of doing it. will explore more)